# When does python compile the constant string letters, to combine the strings into a single constant string?

Tags: python

such as

```
In [9]: dis.disassemble(compile("s = '123' + '456'", "<execfile>", "exec"))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               3 ('123456')
              3 STORE_NAME               0 (s)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

I want to know, when does python combine the constant string as the `CONST`.
If possible, please tell me which source code about this at cpython(whatever 2.x, 3.x).

Comment: Isn't that your answer right there? What are you confused about?

Comment: I think OP wants to know where '123' + '456' turned into '123456'

Comment: @JoelCornett: `'123 + 456'` evaluates in exactly the same way as does `'123456'`. There seems to be no differentiation between `'123`' and `'456'` in `'123 + 456'`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It happens whenever the combined string is 20 characters or fewer.

The optimization occurs in the peephole optimizer.  See line 219 in the `fold_binops_on_constants()` function in *Python/peephole.c*:  http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/cd87afe18ff8/Python/peephole.c#l149

Comment: I wrote Python's peephole optimizer :-)

Comment: Investiganting for a [probably duplicate of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49427151/how-does-python-determine-if-two-strings-are-identical/) I found out that folding has been recently moved to [`ast_opt.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/ast_opt.c), and the maximum size for folded strings is now defined as 4096 (`MAX_STR_SIZE`).

Answer (score 4):

[@Raymond Hetting's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493236/when-does-python-compile-the-constant-string-letters-to-combine-the-constant-st/14493372#14493372) is great, vote for that (I did). I'd make this a comment, but you can't format code in a comment.

If you go over the 20 character limit, the disassembly looks like:

```
>>> dis.disassemble(compile("s = '1234567890' + '09876543210'", "<execfile>", "exec"))
  1  0 LOAD_CONST  0 ('1234567890')
     3 LOAD_CONST  1 ('09876543210')
     6 BINARY_ADD
     7 STORE_NAME  0 (s)
```

But in the case where you have two string literals, remember you can leave out the `+` and use [String literal concatenation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation) to avoid the BINARY_ADD (even when the combined string length is greater than 20):

```
>>> dis.disassemble(compile("s = '1234567890' '09876543210'", "<execfile>", "exec"))
  1  0 LOAD_CONST  0 ('123456789009876543210')
     3 STORE_NAME  0 (s)
```