# How does Python determine if two strings are identical

Tags: python, string, memory

I've tried to understand when Python strings are identical (aka sharing the same memory location). However during my tests, there seems to be no obvious explanation when two string variables that are equal share the same memory:

```
import sys
print(sys.version) # 3.4.3

# Example 1
s1 = "Hello"
s2 = "Hello"
print(id(s1) == id(s2)) # True

# Example 2
s1 = "Hello" * 3
s2 = "Hello" * 3
print(id(s1) == id(s2)) # True

# Example 3
i = 3
s1 = "Hello" * i
s2 = "Hello" * i
print(id(s1) == id(s2)) # False

# Example 4
s1 = "HelloHelloHelloHelloHello"
s2 = "HelloHelloHelloHelloHello"
print(id(s1) == id(s2)) # True

# Example 5
s1 = "Hello" * 5
s2 = "Hello" * 5
print(id(s1) == id(s2)) # False
```

Strings are immutable, and as far as I know Python tries to re-use existing immutable objects, by having other variables point to them instead of creating new objects in memory with the same value.

With this in mind, it seems obvious that `Example 1` returns `True`.
It's still obvious (to me) that `Example 2` returns `True`.

It's not obvious to me, that `Example 3` returns `False` - am I not doing the same thing as in `Example 2`?!?

I stumbled upon this SO question:
[Why does comparing strings in Python using either '==' or 'is' sometimes produce a different result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce/1504742#1504742)

and read through http://guilload.com/python-string-interning/ (though I probably didn't understand it all) and thougt - okay, maybe "interned" strings depend on the length, so I used `HelloHelloHelloHelloHello` in `Example 4`. The result was `True`.

And what the puzzled me, was doing the same as in `Example 2` just with a bigger number (but it would effectively return the same string as `Example 4`) - however this time the result was `False`?!?

I have really no idea how Python decides whether or not to use the same memory object, or when to create a new one.

Are the any official sources that can explain this behavior?

Comment: I don't understand why example 2 and 5 should give different results.

Comment: Why do you care? If you want to enforce this then just intern the strings with `sys.intern()`, otherwise the rules are implementation specific as you know, and therefore not documented by Python

Comment: The second link that you give goes into great detail. It is unlikely that a Stack Overflow answer will be better than that link. The last sentence in your question is actually off-topic (although that doubtless wasn't your intention).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python string interning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541404/python-string-interning)

Comment: The guilload blog post you linked has the answer to your question: "you have to admit that it is hard to tell on which basis a string is natively interned or not. So let’s read some more CPython code and figure it out!"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When does python compile the constant string letters, to combine the constant strings to one constant string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493236/when-does-python-compile-the-constant-string-letters-to-combine-the-constant-st)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the link you posted](http://guilload.com/python-string-interning/):

> **Avoiding large .pyc files**
>
> So why does `'a' * 21 is 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'` not evaluate to `True`? Do you remember the .pyc files you encounter in all your packages? Well, Python bytecode is stored in these files. What would happen if someone wrote something like this `['foo!'] * 10**9`? The resulting *.pyc* file would be huge! In order to avoid this phenomena, sequences generated through peephole optimization are discarded if their length is superior to 20.

If you have the string `"HelloHelloHelloHelloHello"`, Python will necessarily have to store it as it is (asking the interpreter to detect repeating patterns in a string to save space might be too much). However, when it comes to string values that can be computed at parsing time, such as `"Hello" * 5`, Python evaluate those as part of this so-called "peephole optimization", which can decide whether it is worth it or not to precompute the string. Since `len("Hello" * 5) > 20`, the interpreter leaves it as it is to avoid storing too many long strings.

*EDIT:*

As indicated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493236/when-does-python-compile-the-constant-string-letters-to-combine-the-constant-st), you can check this on the source code in [`peephole.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.8/Python/peephole.c), function `fold_binops_on_constants`, near the end you will see:

```
// ...
} else if (size > 20) {
    Py_DECREF(newconst);
    return -1;
}
```

*EDIT 2:*

*Actually*, that optimization code has recently been [moved to the AST optimizer](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/7ea143ae795a9fd57eaccf490d316bdc13ee9065#diff-a33329ae6ae0bb295d742f0caf93c137) for Python 3.7, so now you would have to look into [`ast_opt.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Python/ast_opt.c), function `fold_binop`, which calls now function `safe_multiply`, which checks that the string is no longer than `MAX_STR_SIZE`, [newly defined as 4096](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/2e3f5701858d1fc04caedefdd9a8ea43810270d2). So it seems that the limit has been significantly bumped up for the next releases.

Answer (score 1):

In Example 2 :

```
# Example 2
s1 = "Hello" * 3
s2 = "Hello" * 3
print(id(s1) == id(s2)) # True
```

Here the value of s1 and s2 are evaluated at compile time.so this will return true.

In Example 3 :

```
# Example 3
i = 3
s1 = "Hello" * i
s2 = "Hello" * i
print(id(s1) == id(s2)) # False
```

Here the values of s1 and s2 are evaluated at runtime and the result is not interned automatically so this will return false.This is to avoid excess memory allocation by creating "HelloHelloHello" string at runtime itself.

If you do intern manually it will return True

```
i = 3
s1 = "Hello" * i
s2 = "Hello" * i
print(id(intern(s1)) == id(intern(s2))) # True
```